# Do acetals and hemiacetals give 2,4 DNP test?

Tags: organic-chemistry

Do acetals and hemiacetals give positive 2,4 DNP test?

The reagent for the reaction is described as:

> An aqueous solution of 2,4-dinitrophenyl hydrazine (DNP) is known as Brady's reagent

I recently learnt that acetal don't give positive tollens test whereas hemiacetals did.
Following from the same conclusion I believe that since its an aqueous solution and seems alkaline aswell so according to me acetals should give negative 2,4 DNP Test whereas hemiacetals should give positive.

However I fail to find any literature on this, are my conclusions correct or are there any twists to it!?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard mixture for a 2,4-DNP test contains 2,4-DNP and conc. Sulfuric Acid in EtOH/water [here](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ed082p1310.2). This is sufficient to hydrolyse most acetals and hemi-acetals so they will give a positive test. Cyclic acetals such as dioxolanes are more stable and may not.